# Using a class in a datatype constructor

Tags: haskell

Currently I have something like this:

```
data MyData = SomeData | MoreData | EvenMore
data DataLists = DataLists [MyData] [MyData]
```

Which allows me to obviously do something like this:

```
myDataList :: DataLists
myDataList = DataLists [SomeData, MoreData] [EvenMore, SomeData]
```

But I would like to instead do something like this:

```
-- Static Module File:

class MyClass b where
    evaluate :: b -> Int

data SomeData = SomeData
data MoreData = MoreData
data EvenMore = EvenMore

instance MyClass SomeData where
    evaluate _ = 2
instance MyClass MoreData where
    evaluate _ = 3
instance MyClass EvenMore where
    evaluate _ = 4

data DataList = DataList [MyClass] [MyClass] -- Obviously this is wrong
```

I would like that part of my code to remain static. Because later I would like to add in some types using that module to put in the Data List. I need this separate because the overall module will be used in 2 different projects and I don't want to have to keep going into edit it.

```
data MyVeryOwnData = MyVeryOwnData
--I should be able to make up as many datastructures as I want

instance MyClass MyVeryOwnData where
   evaluate _ = 99

myList :: DataList
myList = DataList [MyVeryOwnData, SomeData] [SomeData, EvenMore]
```

I realize that I could simply put MyVeryOwnData in the module file like this:

```
data MyData = SomeData | MyVeryOwnData ...

instance MyClass MyData where
    evaluate SomeData = 2
    evaluate MoreData = 3
    ... etc.
```

But I dont want to do that since as I said before I want to add an arbitrary amount of datatypes in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is called *Heterogenous lists*, and haskell supports them in mainly two ways, [Existentials](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections#Existential_types) or [GADTs](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT#Existential_types). I show you a runnable code example that solved the problem with existentials.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

class Eval b where
    evaluate :: b -> Int

data SomeData = SomeData
data MoreData = MoreData
data EvenMore = EvenMore

instance Eval SomeData where
    evaluate _ = 2
instance Eval MoreData where
    evaluate _ = 3
instance Eval EvenMore where
    evaluate _ = 4

data Evalable = forall a . Eval a => Evalable a

instance Eval Evalable where
    evaluate (Evalable a) = evaluate a

pack :: Eval a => a -> Evalable
pack = Evalable

data DataLists = DataLists [Evalable] [Evalable]

getFirst :: DataLists -> [Evalable]
getFirst (DataLists xs ys) = xs

main = do
  let dl = DataLists [pack SomeData, pack EvenMore] [pack MoreData]
  print . map evaluate . getFirst $ dl
```

It should be clear that you can add `instance Eval MyVeryOwnData` in outside modules, and you can then `pack` those values so they become `Evalable` and you can then put them inside your `Datalists`.

Comment: You can find more information on this topic at HaskellWiki: [Heterogenous collections](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections).

Comment: Note that using Existentials, you can do *nothing* with `Evalable` besides calling evalute on it (or, in general, what the type class provides). In particular, you cannot pattern-match on the original constructors.

Comment: Ok, maybe this is a really dumb question, but what is the difference between this approach and just evaluating them and storing the evaluated ints in a list?  What advantage is there in storing the preevaluated value if the only permissible operation once packed is to evaluate it?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez In this case, there is no difference, and storing the Ints is likely to be cheaper, too.  In general, though, the type class may have more (and more complex) operations than just `evaluate`; for example, the `Num` class may be useful under an existential in this way.

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame Thanks, although I have another question, then.  For the specific case of `Num`, it wouldn't be useful because all `Num` operations are parametric in the final result, which would be inaccessible since the type parameter is existentially quantified.  However, if you only include classes or portions of classes that have concrete signatures in the positive position, then it seems like you could still do the same trick of just storing the concrete portions in the list.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez For *just* `Num`, I see your point.  However, consider `Integral`:  you can convert arbitrarily between `Integer` and `exists a. (Integral a) => a`, and there are several operations on `a` available inside the scope of the existential.  Morever, when in the scope of the existential, *all the `a`s are the same*.  You don't necessarily have to store only one value of type `a` in your existential datatype.